# Intersection of quadratic equation with exponential equation

Tags: polynomials, quadratics

Two point that are interaction of the curve $y=2^x$ and $y=-2x^2+2$ are defined as $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ where $x_2>x_1$. Then which of the following is/are correct.

A) $x_2>\frac{1}{2}$

B) $y_2-y_1<x_2-x_1$

C) $\frac{\sqrt2}{2}<y_1y_2<1$

The correct option is ABC

[image]

Based on the figure we conclude that ABC is the correct option

I can only prove that $x_2>\frac{1}{2}$

$y=2^{\frac{1}{2}}=\sqrt2$

$y=-2(\frac{1}{2})^2+2$=$\frac{3}{2}$ there the quadratic equation is greater than exponential equation as quadratic equation is decreasing hence $x_2>\frac{1}{2}$

Rest not able to solve

Comment: $y_2-y_1=-2\left(x_1+x_2\right)\left(x_2-x_1\right)$. Show $-2\left(x_1+x_2\right)<1$